# Pandas df.describe() - how do I extract values into Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to do a naive Bayes and after loading some data into a dataframe in Pandas, the describe function captures the data I want.  I'd like to capture the mean and std from each column of the table but am unsure on how to do that.  I've tried things like:

```
df.describe([mean])
df.describe(['mean'])
df.describe().mean
```

None are working.  I was able to do something similar in R with summary but don't know how to do in Python.  Can someone lend some advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
df.describe(include='all').loc['mean']
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Looks like I can capture it as a variable as well.  What if you want two items like mean and std?

Comment: df.describe(include='all').loc[['mean','std']]

Answer (score 9):

You were close. You don't need any `include` tag. Just rewrite your second approach correctly: `df.describe()['mean']`

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s.describe()['mean']
# 3.0
```

If you want both `mean` and `std`, just write `df.describe()[['mean', 'std']]`. For example,

```
s.describe()[['mean', 'std']]
# mean    3.000000
# std     1.581139
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says: KeyError: "['mean' 'std'] not in index".  Any idea why that would occur?

Comment: @Vaslo: You missed a comma between 'mean' and 'std'. Try again with a comma

Comment: If still the problem persists, please include some dataframe in your question

Comment: I think the issue is that I am trying to use on a 2D frame.  When I use your example it works fine but when I try to do it exactly cut and paste as you explain it is giving me an error.

Comment: @Vaslo: Can you try `df_1 = pd.Series(df.values.ravel())` and then try `df_1.describe()[['mean', 'std']]`?

Comment: When i use the example you posted it works and gives me a single mean and single std.  Mine should have a column of means and stds (one for each column)

Comment: Try what I wrote in my comment before uploading the dataframe and see if it works

Comment: I tried the df_1 = pd.Series(df.values.ravel())  and it works, but returns just a single std and mean, so maybe that is my issue?  I have a 767x9 dataframe that I am trying to extract 9 means from.

Comment: Many thanks - the solution below by @milos.ai gives me a subset of the describe dataframe.  For future reference, how do I upload a frame, or do I just type it into the space?

Comment: You can copy paste the frame after printing it using `df.head()` for example. People can then simply copy your dataframe and then use `pd.read_clipboard()` to create a dataframe out of it. To get more idea, just click on the pandas or dataframe tag below your question and then see how other question have done it.

Comment: I had to use python 2.7 to use some other libraries at work and I had to use `include='all'` to get it working.

Answer (score 6):

If you further want to extract specific column data then try:

```
df.describe()['FeatureName']['mean']
```

Replace mean with any other statistic you want to extract

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('./FileName.csv')
data.describe().loc['mean']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `mean` or the `std` of a column of your dataframe, you don't need to go through `describe()`. Instead, the proper way would be to just call the respective statistical function on the column (which really is a `pandas.core.series.Series`). Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# crate dataframe with some numerical data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'B': [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]})

print(df['A'].mean()) # 5.5
print(df['B'].std())  # 2.8751811537130436
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#computations-descriptive-stats) for the descriptive stats that are built into the pandas `Series`.

(Let me know if I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do here.)

Answer (score -1):

yeah bro i am faced same problem after seeing these solutions i tried it.luckly one get worked.here i worked on the 75% in describe function this is my code`d=bank.groupby(by=['region','Gender']).get_group(('south Moravia','Female')) d.cashwdn.describe()['75%']`

Comment: I think your answer is both lacking clarity and it is falling short in language/tone.